# Ionic. How to use storage and get real results

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, promise, ionic2

I have been killing myself trying to get basic info in and out of persistent storage in ionic. Here is my code for getting a couple of keys from storage (say a username and password)

```
export const getMultiple = function(storage, keys: string[]) {
  const promises = [];

  keys.forEach( key => promises.push(storage.get(key)) );

  return Promise.all(promises).then( values => {
    const result = {};

    values.map( (value, index) => { 
      result[keys[index]] = value; 
    });
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  });
}
```

However if I call `getMultiple('uesrname' 'password')` This is the result I get:

> t {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array[0]}

instead of

> Object {email: null, password: null}

which is what the console logs out with `console.log(result);`. Any idea why I am not reciving this return statement?

**NOTE**
I have attempted removing the `return Promise.all ...` However then it returns an `undefined`

**TLDR**
How do I make my program wait till I have the result from this promise to return the data?

Comment: What is the storage object? Did it fire ready? storage.ready()? Can you get all the keys from storage by doing storage.keys()?

Comment: My general issue is getting data back from a promise. Why is storage async anyway?

Comment: The objects are currently null in storage as that would be the case when the app is first loaded up. however they can be retrieved as the log shows. However this happens after the weird t object has been returned.

Comment: that's a super duper good question.

Comment: The console outputs live, so it will represent the end result, not necessarily what your code reads at that point in time. This should indicate to you that you are actually processing a result before it is ready, so you are probably mishandling a promise somewhere. I suspect it is in the `storage.get(key))`. You may wish to add a `.then(result => return result;` to that statement.

Comment: @PhillipHartin Unfortunately the return statement is not executing up the chain. so for example .then(result => return result) actually does nothing (I still only receive the promise)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on this, but I think you are looping your keys incorrectly for the use of promises.

I've rewritten your foreach method using an Array.map to create an array of promises for the work you want to perform on the individual keys/values, then wait on them all with Promise.all. In this example I have just appended the `result` of each `storage.get()` to an array of `results`. The array of results will be returned only once all the `storage.get()` calls have successfully responded. Which I think is what you want.

```
export const getMultiple = function(storage, keys: string[]) {

    let results = [];

    // Use a map
    return Promise.all(keys.map(key => {

        return storage.get(key).then(result => {
            // Perform some action on the result - add to an array, or whatever.
            results.push(result);
            return result;
        });

    })).then(() => {
        // This will run after all the promises have been resolved.
        return results;
    });
```

Give it a go and let me know.

Comment: It did not change anything. I am still receiving the same bad results :-(

Comment: @MHornbacher 

So when you run 
`this.getMultiple.then(result => { console.log(result) });`
you do not get an array back?

Comment: No, I need to set it to a variable. I half solved the problem by engineering a workaround :-(. Still do not understand why I cannot just tell the framework to wait for promise x to finish running so I can get the result back.

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly write return in async method.

```
//Call this method from anyhwere u want to store the data in local Storage.
 setToLocalStorage(key, value) {
if (key && value) {
 // console.log(key, ' is set to local storage and value :', value);
  this.storage.set(key, value);
}
else {
  console.log(key, value, 'is null or undefined');
}
}

 //Call this method from anywhere u want to get data.
 async getFromLocalStorage(key) {
 if (key) {
 // console.log(key, ' is get to local storage');
  return await this.storage.get(key);
 }
else {
  console.log(key, 'is null or undefined');
}
}
```